# Not able to connect over wifi

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I installed latest ubuntu LTS image on my old acer  V laptop .  It does not find wirless adapter. From top right hand incon in "setting" it only shows wired connection info.  It connects using ethernet.

I ran the command  lshw -C network and below is the output

description: Network controller

```
   product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:19 memory:b0500000-b0503fff
```

As you can see it does say I have boradcom wirless card.  it even says the driver=bcma-pci-bridge.
Inspite of this I am not seeing wireless tab in setting (only the wired tab) and not able to connect over wifi because it does not see any wifi.